# Bootcamp - "Can’t install the software because it is not currently available from the Software Update server." Error

Tags: windows, bootcamp, partition

I'm trying to install Windows 10 on my MacBook Pro 2019 Intel device, but unable to use Bootcamp.

After selection of ISO and partition size, the application throws this error even tho I have a stable connection:
[image]

I'm able to download WindowsSupport files manually, but I don't know what to do with them.

I tried creating a USB bootable for installation, but NTFS/MS-DOS/exFAT partition won't be showing in disk list on Windows Setup screen.

I'm open for any suggestions for both of the issues.

Comment: How did you try creating a USB bootable for installation? Have you created any partitions on the internal drive for Windows?

Comment: @David Anderson I’ve created a partition on my internal drive and then restart the mac on the bootable installer USB. But in the setup processes, when the installer asks for to select a partition, there are no disks showing.

Answer (score 2):

The most likely cause is the USB bootable does not contain the files that the installer needs to read in order to load the driver that would allow access to the internal drive. Or, the files are in the wrong location. These files are included in the Windows Support Software that can be downloaded using the Boot Camp Assistant. To insure the correct Windows Support Software for your Mac is downloaded, the Boot Camp Assistant should be executed on the Mac where Windows is to be installed. Although the OP is installing Windows 10, the placement of the Windows Support Software is described in step 11 of section "[Follow these steps if you downloaded version 5 of Windows Support Software](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205016#version5)" in the Apple article "[Install Windows 7 on your Mac using Boot Camp](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205016)". Note the following.

- Although the article is for Windows 7, the step also applies to any version of Windows newer than Windows 7.
- The version of the Windows Support Software for the Mac is undoubtedly newer than version 5.
- The `AutoUnattend.xml` will probably be missing from the Windows Support Software. For most (in not all) newer Intel Macs, this file is automatically generated by the Boot Camp Assistant and therefore will be unavailable since the OP has stated this part of the installation has failed. Installing without this file will require manually preforming tasks that otherwise would be occur automatically.

Answer (score 0):

[My answer given on 13/09/2023]: I guess you started here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO

You say you have the support files: this being the case i.e. you have driver files and bootcamp setup on the 16GB USB; I'll tell you how I did this on both a 2018 Mac Mini running Ventura 13.6 & a 2014 Mac Mini running Monterey {without using the BOOTCAMP utility (as you say you have the support files)}.

[1] Use disk utility to partition off e.g. 100GB then formatting to ExFat with GUID for EFI booting capability.
[2] Create using RUFUS on a Windows machine a bootable USB for Windows 10
[3] For the 2014 Mac Mini restarting and holding down the option aka alt key will give an option to start via the Windows bootable 16GB USB (this will also be true on the 2018 Mac Mini - If SIP is disabled {more complex if it isn't!
[4] install Windows 10 on the partition (e.g. 100GB) created in step [1] Next:
[5] plug in the USB with the support files on and run setup for bootcamp
[6] Follow the dialogues to finish the job. All the best.
[5]