# Bootcamp : Can’t install the software because it is not currently available from the Software Update server

Tags: windows, bootcamp, dual-boot

I'm trying to install windows 11 on my 2019 macbook pro with MacOs 12.3.1. However when execute bootcamp, after the selection of the iso it is stuck with this error message :

> Can’t install the software because it is not currently available from the Software Update server.

I tried to manually download it from "Action > Download Windows Support Software" and save it into download aaaannnd it works... So I'm a bit confused here.

I know someone else has the same problem (here [Bootcamp - "Can’t install the software because it is not currently available from the Software Update server." Error](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/436905/bootcamp-can-t-install-the-software-because-it-is-not-currently-available-fro)) but there is no valid answer yet... So I just try again...

Thank you for all the help you can bring :-)

Comment: I highly doubt installing Windows 11 by using the Boot Camp Assistant is going to be successful. Windows 11 by default requires a Trusted Platform Module (TPM) version 2.0 which your Mac does not have. So if you were able to download the Windows Support Software, then you might as well pursue installing without further use of the Boot Camp Assistant.

Comment: According microsoft, windows 11 is compatible with the CPU.
But the problem seems to occur before the installation of Windows in my case :/

I started to try installing it without boot camp,  but I cannot boot on my key for now.... Everytime I have an error of "Unable to verify boot disk" or something...

Comment: The new requirements to install Window 11 imposed by Microsoft can not be overcome by using the Boot Camp Assistant. So, even if you get pass the problem asked in your question, you will not be able to install Windows 11 on your machine. You will have to come up with some sort of hack that will not be provided by Apple. For example, see this [question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/436972/install-windows-11-on-boot-camp) and this [question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/431583/bootcamp-control-panel-causes-bsod-in-early-2011-macbookpro-with-windows-11).

Comment: Ok I see now ! Thank you so much for your time and answers!